# why does a single web request create a second separate thread call to my defaultdocument page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis-7, default-document

I'm seeing some very strange behaviour when debugging my web application in VS2010 locally. The same user journey/sequence of pages happens in Production.

Debugging, I'm seeing this:

```
1. request for MyPage.aspx - handled by thread_1
2. (there is something on that page that IIS/ASP.Net doesn't like it seems) I'm slowly removing sections to pin-point exactly but there's
no JS, or anything fancy there just html content, user controls etc.
3. Either way a separate thread_2 to begin processing the Page_Load of my defaultdocument i.e. home.aspx is executed. There is logic in
home.aspx.cs to clear some data.
4. So when thread_1 continues processing, checks against the data above fail, resulting with the user being redirected to an error page.
```

Can anyone shed any light on why the second thread is created and why it starts to process my default document?

Please note:

- I've checked the global methods for errors e.g. session_end,
  app_error etc but nothing.
- I do intermittently see a 401 error with Failed Request Tracing Logging enabled but I don't understand how that would start the
  processing of my default home page?
- just to sanity check, I placed a new doc test.aspx at the beginning of my defaultdocument list in the web.config and it did get called.

It seems as though, something within IIS/ASP.Net is configured to begin processing the default page on an error but this is new behaviour to me?

I've tried researching this but the only thing that seems that it could be related is thread-agility but I'm not too sure..?

Comment: How exactly are you identifying these threads? Are you debugging with iis express? Its normally all executed on a single thread.

Comment: Threads view in VS2010 shows separate threads with different id's.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is your home.aspx page_load executed twice? Are you skipping your default document? Is there a redirect? Need more info/code.

Comment: Please read the numbers. The user is browsing the site and reaches the problematic MyPage. During the processing of that page, program flow execution is diverted to home.aspx? If you have experienced this change of execution to a separate thread which runs through the defaultdocument please advise? There's no redirect. It's this strange behaviour which jumps to the home page I need someone who has experience of to help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing a lot of content within the faulty MyPage.aspx, I came across the guilty line of code: `btnShowPost.ImageUrl = SitePath + "post.png";` (it was never accessed behind an if statement) and therefore the image `<asp:Image ID="btnShowPost" runat="server" />` never set the necessary ImageUrl.

Without it, apparently this is standard browser behavior: any img, script, css, etc, with a
src= missing, will use the default path as the url. iis will usually redirect to default.aspx (or whatever is the default).

[See full explanation on this link](http://iisissuebxv.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/strange-issue-with-imagebutton-with-no.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are two HTTP requests running concurrently. As each request (generally) executes on its on thread this condition would make sense.

HTTP requests by default do not share state. They operate on different data. For that reason this is not a thread-safety issue.

An exception to this rule is if you explicitly share state e.g. using static variables. You shouldn't do this for various reasons.

To debug the problem launch Fiddler and examine the HTTP request being executed. Also example `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` on each of the two concurrent threads.

Comment: Thanks usr. I've been using Fiddler from the start and it just shows a single request for the error page that the user ends up on. So the user clicks on a button on the menu.aspx page. This does a JS window.location.href (redirect) to MyPage.aspx. 
From that page this strange behavior begins. While debugging I get the Page_Load of MyPage.aspx (as expected), RawUrl = MyPage.aspx.
I then get another thread in the Page_Load of home.aspx (my first defaultdocument as configured in web.config), RawUrl = home.aspx.
So yes, 2 requests but where/why the 2nd is created? Error Handling in IIS maybe??